# select last visit date in Laravel (Mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to select last visit date in `php` (`Laravel`). First I order by descending and then select the maximum date. Can any body help me?

Here is my unsuccessful code:

```
   $getlast = DB::table('tr_visit')
        ->join('tm_child','tm_child.Child_ID','=','tr_visit.Child_ID')
        ->where('tm_child.Child_Name', 'LIKE', '%'.$input.'%')
        ->where('tm_child.Child_ID','=','CH001')
        ->orderBy('tr_visit.Visit_Date', 'desc')
        ->select(DB::raw('max(tr_visit.Visit_Date),Visit_Date'))
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 $getlast = DB::table('tr_visit')
        ->join('tm_child','tm_child.Child_ID','=','tr_visit.Child_ID')
        ->where('tm_child.Child_Name', 'LIKE', '%'.$input.'%')
        ->where('tm_child.Child_ID','=','CH001')
        ->orderBy('tr_visit.Visit_Date', 'desc')
        ->select(DB::raw('max(tr_visit.Visit_Date),Visit_Date'))
        ->first();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are already ordering by the date descending, there is no need to select the maximum. The first row will be the maximum date.

```
->orderBy('tr_visit.Visit_Date','desc')
->first();
```

Should be all you need.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to order by date in descending order,then you have to use `DATE` like this

```
    ->orderBy("DATE('tr_visit.Visit_Date')",'desc')
    ->first();
```